# Is there a terminology for verbs describing the subject?

Tags: verbs

Is there a terminology for verbs describing the state of an subject? For example:

```
He is a man
He suffers from headache
He lives in America
He loves swimming
```

As compare to an action against an object:

```
He ate an apple 
He took away my book
```

If possible, I would like to have access to a complete of verbs of both types.

Comment: [Stative verbs](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/stative-verbs/) are verbs that express a state rather than an action. Is that what you're getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates that describe states (they're not all verbs) are called ***Stative*** predicates.
Predicates that describe actions are called **Active** predicates.  This sense of "active" does not
contrast with the Passive construction; the active/stative distinction is semantic, not grammatical.

- *He is a man*    -    Predicate nouns are stative
- *He is very tired.* -  Most predicate adjectives are stative
- *He is in the garden.* - Most phrasal predicates are stative
  (non-verbal predicates require an auxiliary verb *be* to carry tense.)

But there are lots of stative verbs, too:

- *He owns a house in Ypsilanti.*  - *Own* is stative, though *rent* is active.
- *He loves swimming*  - Mental state predicates are stative.
- *He suffers from migraines*  - Physical state predicates are stative.
- *He lives in America*  - Locative predicates are stative.

Though most adjectives are stative, there are some active ones; they mean 'act like `X`'

- *He's being honest*. - *Honest* can be active, and thus can be used in the progressive.

Comment: +1 How about sentences like *He survived the hurricane*?